# Azure DevOps 2020 Application Pool stop working after Sharepoint Uninstall

Tags: sharepoint, azure-devops-server

So, as these types of posts usually start, I inherited an old Azure DevOps server (currently On-Premise DevOps 2020, running on Windows Server 2016) that I am now running mostly by myself (and as these things also usually go I'm a developer not a DevOps-Engineer :x).

Our internal IT informed me that they noticed a lot of critical events while doing some maintenance on that DevOps so they informed me. I looked into it and found a old Sharepoint Server Installation (SharePoint 2016) that caused these critical errors, saying something about some sharepoint component that couldnt be found.

I quickly talked to an older colleague who told me we used to have TF2013 with Sharepoint Integration so I looked into it, but the management tool wouldn't start, all the IIS-websites and application pools for it were disabled so we figured it was "dead" anyways.

I run the uninstaller using the "Add or Remove Programs" option in Windows and after a few minutes already our DevOps is, of course, unavailable (503). It takes forever (2 hours or so) but I figure it has something to do with IIS being reconfigured and wait until it finishes.

After the installation I still had error 503 so I restarted everything (IIS, Application Pools, websites) seeing if that would help - it didn't. Looking at the  Event Viewer I found the following errors:

- Under Windows Logs/Application:
  `The Module DLL C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\isapi\spnativerequestmodule.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.`
- Under Windows Logs/System: `Application pool 'Azure DevOps Server Application Pool' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.`
- Under Application and Services Logs\Microsoft-Team Foundation Server\Debug: 3 different errors saying "No supported Version found for extension: ms.vss-services-x (x being endpoint, docker and jenkins, though I don't think we're really using docker and we're certainly not using Jenkins so that may be a red herring)

Online I found some similar-ish errors and the solution was usually something about running 32-bit applications that was solved with this command line: `“appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/globalModules /[name='SPNativeRequestModule'].preCondition:integratedMode,bitness64”`
I don't feel like that would help me (and I don't want to randomly try on productive system) so I haven't tried that yet though. Also the application pool is set to 64-bit.

Any idea what I can check or do to get my application pool running again? I have no clue why DevOps would depend on some SharePoint component, as far as I'm aware Microsoft stopped Sharepoint Integration after DevOps 2018. Please help me, you're my only hope, lol

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue: Apparently SP adds some of its components to the entire server as a native module. Through IIS Manager -> (local PC) -> Modules -> "Configure Native Modules" I was able to remove the reference to spnativerequestmodule.dll, now my TFS is back up and (hopefully) functional.

Hope this helps some desperate soul in the future at least, lol.